# Expected range of simple random walk in $\mathbb{Z^2}$

Tags: stochastic-processes, random-walk

Let $(Y_k)_{k\geq0}$ be a simple random walk process. The range of an $n$-step random walk, $R_n$, is
a random variable that characterizes the number of distinct points visited at time $n$:
$$R_n=|\{Y_0, Y_1 \dots Y_n \}|$$
Prove that if $(Y_k)_{k\geq0}$ is a SRW on $\mathbb{Z^2}$ then
$$ \mathbb{E}(R_n)\asymp \frac{n}{\log n},$$

where $f(n)\asymp g(n)$ means that $\exists c, C \in (0, \infty): c<\frac{f(n)}{g(n)}<C$.

The desired result is mentioned e.g. in [this article](http://ecp.ejpecp.org/article/view/1072):

*'The simple random walk (SRW) in $\mathbb{Z^2}$visits about $n/ \log n$ points by time $n$.'*

On the other hand unfortunately there is no explanation or reference to this assertion.
Do you know a relatively simple (e.g. using Green's function, reflection principle, CLT etc.) proof to this claim?

Thank you very much for your help in advance!

Comment: I don't really understand why this question was put on hold as off-topic. I think this as interesting mathematical concept.
I tried to improve the question with additional details.
I have examined a number of other questions on this side and I don't see why this question is poorly worded. I would be grateful if you could help me.

Comment: Your most recent revision has promoted this question from being a moderately interesting context-less request for help to a clear, well-focused and well-motivated question of the type we cannot ever have enough of. Good job :).

Comment: I searched on the web, and found this article www.renyi.hu/~major/articles/random-walk.pdf, which seem to have a related result that might inspire you. It shows that if $\alpha(n)$ is the number of points visited exactly once up to time $n$ by a random walk, then $\text{limsup}_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{\alpha(n)}{\log^2(n)}=C$ for some constant $C$. Notice that this is for a simple random walk in one dimension, and I haven't read the proof, but maybe it can be modified from "visited exactly once" to "visited", and extended to two dimensions.

Comment: For a good introduction to the subject, with relevant references and a proof that, for the simple random walk in two dimensions, $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{\log n}{n}E(R_n)=\pi,$$ see this [master's thesis](http://www.math.upenn.edu/~pemantle/papers/Student-theses/Masters/Jiao140506.pdf).

Comment: @ Did @HowDoIMath Thank you very much for the links. To tell the truth I am still looking for a shorter, relatively simple proof.

Answer (score 1):

This is an old question, but as someone might stumble on it at some point, let me try to sketch the argument that can be found in details in this [paper](https://projecteuclid.org/ebooks/berkeley-symposium-on-mathematical-statistics-and-probability/Proceedings-of-the-Second-Berkeley-Symposium-on-Mathematical-Statistics-and/chapter/Some-Problems-on-Random-Walk-in-Space/bsmsp/1200500239) from Dvoretzky and Erdös.

First, we notice that we can write $\mathbb{E}(R_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \gamma(i)$, where $\gamma(i)$ denotes the probability that $Y$ visits at time $i$ a point it has not yet visited.

We now compute:

\begin{align*}
\gamma(n) := P(Y_n \neq Y_i, 1 \leq i \leq n-1) &= P \left(\sum_{j=i+1}^n X_j \neq 0, 1 \leq i \leq n-1 \right) \\
&= P \left(\sum_{j=1}^{n-i} X_j \neq 0, 1 \leq i \leq n-1 \right) \\
&= P(Y_i \neq 0, 1 \leq i \leq n-1), \\
\end{align*}

using simple properties of the SRW (independence, symmetry).

Next, we compare $\gamma(i)$ with the probability to return to zero in $i$ steps:

\begin{align}
1 &= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} P(Y_i=0, Y_j \neq 0 \; \forall j=i+1, \dots, n-1) \nonumber \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} P(Y_i=0) P(Y_j-Y_i \neq 0 \; \forall j=i+1, \dots, n-1) \nonumber \\
&= \sum_{i=0}^{n-1} P(Y_i=0) \gamma(n-i). \tag{1}
\end{align}

For $i$ odd the summand is zero, and for the rest we estimate:

$$P(Y_{2i}=0)= \binom{2i}{i}^2 = \frac{1}{\pi i} + o \left(\frac{1}{i} \right).$$

Notice now that

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\lfloor (n-1)/2 \rfloor} P(Y_{2i}=0) = \pi \ln n + O(1)$$

(where the constant can be taken uniform on $n$).

From this we get the lower bound, as from the observation that $\gamma(i+1) \leq \gamma(i)$ we can get from $(1)$ that $\gamma(n) \leq \frac{(1 + o(1))\pi}{\ln n}$, resulting in

$$\mathbb{E}(R_n) = \sum_{i=1}^n \gamma(i) \leq \frac{(1 + o(1))\pi n}{\ln n}$$

when comparing the sum with an integral, for instance.

For the other direction, one can start again from $(1)$ and, for $k \leq n$ arbitrary, bound $\gamma(i) \leq \gamma(n-k)$ for $i \geq n-k$ and $\gamma(i) \leq 1$ for $i < n-k$:

\begin{align*}
1 \leq \sum_{i=0}^{k-1} P(Y_i=0) + \gamma(n-k) \sum_{i=k}^{n-1} P(Y_i=0).
\end{align*}

Then, a similar analysis allows to conclude.

Maybe it is worth mentioning that since $R_n$ is sub-additive, by Kingman's subadditive ergodic theorem there exists $\beta \geq 0$ such that $\mathbb{E}(R_n)/n \xrightarrow[n \to \infty]{}\beta$. In the case of $\mathbb{Z}^2$, this is zero, and the right rate of convergence is $1/\ln n$ as we have seen, but on graphs where the SRW is transient -- such as $\mathbb{Z}^d, d \geq 3$ -- it is strictly positive, which can be seen with an analysis similar to the one above.